# What is the expected number of times that the phrase will appear in the sentence?

Tags: probability, markov-chains

You create a random sentence of length n by repeatedly picking words at random from the
vocabulary {a, is, not,rose}, with each word being equally likely to be picked. What is the
expected number of times that the phrase “a rose is a rose” will appear in the sentence?

Comment: How do you count “a rose is a rose is a rose”?  Is that $1$ or $2$?  In any case you can set up a recurrence relation.  Have you tried?  Have you computed some small terms?

Comment: a rose is a rose is a rose count 2

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the sentence is $S = w_1w_2\cdots w_n$. Define random variables $X_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq n - 4$ as
$$
X_i =
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if }\ w_iw_{i+1}\cdots w_{i+4} = \text{"a rose is a rose"} \\
0 & \text { otherwise }
\end{cases}
$$
The number of "a rose is a rose" in $S$ is therefore
$$
X = \sum_{i=1}^{n-4} X_i
$$
Thus
$$
\mathbb{E}[X] = \sum_{i=1}^{n-4} \mathbb{E}[X_i] = (n-4)\cdot \frac{1}{4^5}
$$